# Не работает корутина после деактивации и повторной активации скрипта в Unity3d

Tags: unity3d, coroutine

столкнулся с проблемой при разработке 2d игры в unity3d. Есть два объекта: солдат и точка его респауна. На солдате висит скрипт, позволяющий стрелять левой и правой кнопками мыши:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SoldierShooting : MonoBehaviour
{  
    public Transform bulletFirePoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    private float bulletForce = 15f;
    private bool canShoot = true; // добавляем переменную для проверки, можно ли выпустить следующую пулю дробовика

    private IEnumerator ShootCoroutine()
    {

        canShoot = false; // устанавливаем флаг, что выстрел нельзя выпустить
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Shoot();
        }   // выпускаем пять пуль
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); // ждем 1 секунду
        canShoot = true; // устанавливаем флаг, что можно выстрелить снова
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
        {
            Debug.Log("ПКМ!");
            if (!canShoot)
            {
                return;
            }
            StartCoroutine(ShootCoroutine());
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletFirePoint.position, bulletFirePoint.rotation);
        Rigidbody2D rigidBodyOfBullet = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rigidBodyOfBullet.AddForce(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Random.Range(-16, 16)) * bulletFirePoint.up * bulletForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

На точке респауна висит скрипт, который деактивирует солдата нажатием кнопки "E" для того, чтобы он исчезал с игрового поля и не взаимодействовал с другими игровыми объектами до повторной активации:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerActivator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject soldier;
    
    public Transform spawnPoint; // Ссылка на объект, который будет использоваться для установки начальной позиции и направления солдата

    private bool isActive = false;

   private void Start()
    {        
        SetActive(false); // Солдат начинает игру неактивным и невидимым
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // При нажатии на кнопку "E" меняем активность солдата
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            isActive = !isActive;
            SetActive(isActive);
        }
    }

    private void SetActive(bool active)
    {
        
        // Если солдат становится неактивным, то мы делаем его невидимым и отключаем его возможность взаимодействовать с окружающим миром
        if (!active)
        {
            soldier.SetActive(false);
        }
        // Если солдат становится активным, то мы делаем его видимым и включаем его возможность управлять им
        else
        {
            soldier.SetActive(true);
            // Устанавливаем позицию и направление солдата в соответствии с spawnPoint
            soldier.transform.position = spawnPoint.position;
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос состоит в том, что если я деактивирую солдата до того, как корутина прекращает своё действие, то при повторной активации солдата корутина не работает. Не знаю, как это исправить. Солдат просто не реагирует на нажатие правой кнопки мыши "Fire2" при повторной активации. Замечу, что если выстрелить правой кнопкой мыши, подождать завершения корутины и деактивировать солдата, то при повторной активации корутина работает исправно.

Заранее прошу прощения за, вероятно, корявый код, не верное оформление вопроса и прочее. Я не профессионал и это мой первый пост. Спасибо за понимание.

РЕШЕНО

Спасибо за подсказку @igoefi.
Починил путём добавления в скрипт SoldierShooting следующего блока:

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    canShoot = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя в корутине `canShoot` задаëтся как `false`. И при внеплановом завершении корутины до еë конца, у тебя `canShoot` не становится `true`, следовательно ты не сможешь стрелять